# Bounds on the difference of sups in terms of the Hausdorff distance between feasible regions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, supremum-and-infimum, uniform-continuity, hausdorff-distance

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{k} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded and continuous function, and suppose that $X \subset \mathbb{R}^{k}$ and $Y \subset \mathbb{R}^{k}$ are compact.

I am reading a paper that claims:
\begin{align}
\left| \sup_{x \in X} f(x) - \sup_{y \in Y} f(y)  \right| \leq \sup_{||x-y|| \leq d_{H}(X,Y)} \left|f(x) - f(y) \right|
\end{align}
where $d_{H}(X,Y)$ is the Hausdorff distance between $X$ and $Y$:
\begin{align}
d_{H}(X,Y) = \max\left\{\sup_{x \in X} \inf_{y \in Y} ||x-y||, \: \sup_{y \in Y} \inf_{x \in X} ||x-y|| \right\}
\end{align}
The paper uses it as an intermediate step in a longer proof, and does not give a proof of this result. I have tried to prove it myself, but have not made much progress (in fact I am not even sure if it is true).

Can anyone provide a proof of (or counterexample to) this result? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't too hard but it takes a little work to set everything up rigorously if you start from definitions.

For any $\epsilon > d_H(X,Y)$ define $X_\epsilon = \{z \mid \mathrm{dist}(z,X) < \epsilon\}$ and $Y_\epsilon = \{z \mid \mathrm{dist}(z,Y) < \epsilon\}$. By definition of Hausdorff distance you have $X \subset Y_\epsilon$ and $Y \subset X_\epsilon$.

For each $n \ge 1$ define $\epsilon_n = d_H(X,Y) + \frac 1n$.

Fix a point $x \in X$. Then $x \in Y_{\epsilon_n}$, so there exists $y_n \in Y$ with $\|x-y_n\| < \epsilon_n$. In particular
$$f(x) \le |f(x) - f(y_n)| + f(y_n) \le |f(x) - f(y_n)| + \sup_{y \in Y} f(y).$$

This works for all $n$. Since $Y$ is compact there exists a subsequence $\{y_{n_k}\}$ that converges to a point $z \in Y$. Since $f$ is continuous you may conclude 
$$ f(x) \le |f(x) - f(z)| + \sup_{y \in Y} f(y).$$
Moreover since
$$ \|x-z\| \le \|x - y_{n_k}\| + \|y_{n_k} - z\| \le d_H(X,Y) + \frac 1{n_k} + \|y_{n_k} -z\|$$
it follows that $\|x - z\| \le d_H(X,Y)$, and thus 
$$|f(x) - f(z)| \le \sup_{\|x-y\| \le d_H(X,Y)} |f(x) - f(y)|.$$

Finally you get
$$f(x) \le \sup_{\|x-y\| \le d_H(X,Y)} |f(x) - f(y)| + \sup_{y \in Y} f(y).$$
The '$x$' on the right-hand side is now a dummy letter - it doesn't represent the fixed '$x$' on the left. You can take the supremum over all $x \in X$ to get what you are looking for: 
$$\sup_{x \in X} f(x) \le \sup_{\|x-y\| \le d_H(X,Y)} |f(x) - f(y)| + \sup_{y \in Y} f(y).$$

The argument is completed by reversing the roles of $X$ and $Y$ to obtain the corresponding inequality.